# Установка компилятора SR

Tags: linux, c, gcc

Помогите с установкой компилятора SR, нужен только для одной маленькой программы, с синтаксисом разобрался, но с установкой компилятора возникли непонятки. Сайт: https://www2.cs.arizona.edu/sr/impl.html. OC Linux 32-бит.

Comment: Распаковываете, компилируете, устанавливаете. Это же *Старая ШКОЛА* ;)

Comment: Вот этот http://paste.ubuntu.org.cn/4244562 патч поможет собрать из исходников, только пути поправьте как у вас в системе. Но вообще прикольно неподготовленному старой школой пользователю, да.

Comment: Не понимаю, каким образом заюзать патч

Comment: `patch p1 < file.diff`. Но он полностью не спасает (потом сама эта среда валится, если компилятор 64-битный в режиме совместимости). Это только первая часть, дальше интереснее (вам), мне уже нет ;) Удачи! Напоследок могу порекомендовать пробовать это всё в 32-битном окружении, так будет проще.

Comment: Пробовал собрать файл make, что-то компилило, потом выбило yacc -d grammar.y 
make[1]: yacc: Команда не найдена
Makefile:52: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «grammar.c»
make[1]: *** [grammar.c] Ошибка 127
make[1]: выход из каталога «/home/lootsik/sr/sr»
Makefile:23: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «all»
make: *** [all] Ошибка 2 
Эхх, сложно на линкусе что-то делать без опыта

Comment: Установите вариант лексического парсера `yacc`, В Linux чаще всего используется имплементация `bison`.

Comment: Установил, появилась новая ошибка        
<встроенное>: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «print.o»

make[1]: *** [print.o] Ошибка 1
make[1]: выход из каталога «/home/lootsik/sr/sr»
Makefile:23: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «all»
make: *** [all] Ошибка 2

Comment: после нескольких ошибок: undeclared (first use in this function)